# Python script not picking up the correct date selected in the excel Macro

Tags: python, vba, excel

I am trying to run a macro in excel that generates monthly reports.The macro calls the python script without any problems. However no matter the month i choose in the macro the python script always runs for January.

This is where i select the month:
[image: This is where i select the month.]

When the python script runs it is always January:
[image: When the python script runs it is always January.]

Here is the code in python script.

```
#Read the month and year selected in the Monthly Report
pathOfMonthlyReportFile = os.sep.join((os.path.expanduser("~"), 
'Desktop'))+'\Monthly Activity Report - Template.xlsm'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(pathOfMonthlyReportFile, keep_vba=True)
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Macro')
MonthOfMonthlyReport = sheet['G10'].value
YearOfMonthlyReport = sheet['J10'].value
print(MonthOfMonthlyReport)

if MonthOfMonthlyReport == "January":
 MonthNumber = 1
elif MonthOfMonthlyReport == "February":
 MonthNumber = 2
elif MonthOfMonthlyReport == "March":
 MonthNumber = 3
elif MonthOfMonthlyReport == "April":
 MonthNumber = 4
elif MonthOfMonthlyReport == "May":
 MonthNumber = 5
elif MonthOfMonthlyReport == "June":
 MonthNumber = 6
elif MonthOfMonthlyReport == "July":
 MonthNumber = 7
elif MonthOfMonthlyReport == "August":
 MonthNumber = 8
elif MonthOfMonthlyReport == "September":
 MonthNumber = 9
elif MonthOfMonthlyReport == "October":
 MonthNumber = 10
elif MonthOfMonthlyReport == "November":
 MonthNumber = 11
elif MonthOfMonthlyReport == "December":
 MonthNumber = 12

MonthlyReportDate = 
now.replace(month=MonthNumber,year=int(YearOfMonthlyReport))
if MonthNumber == 12:
last_day_of_month = MonthlyReportDate.replace(day = 31, month=MonthNumber, 
year=int(YearOfMonthlyReport))
else:
last_day_of_month = MonthlyReportDate.replace(day=1, month=MonthNumber+1, 
year=int(YearOfMonthlyReport)) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

if MonthNumber >= 10:
    stringenddate = "%s-%s-%s" % (MonthlyReportDate.year, 
MonthlyReportDate.month,last_day_of_month.day)
    stringstartdate = "%s-%s-01" % (MonthlyReportDate.year, 
MonthlyReportDate.month)
else:
    stringenddate = "%s-0%s-%s" % (MonthlyReportDate.year, 
MonthlyReportDate.month,last_day_of_month.day)
    stringstartdate = "%s-0%s-01" % (MonthlyReportDate.year, 
MonthlyReportDate.month)

print(stringenddate)

MonthRange = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
ThreeMonthsAgo = 0

for i in range(len(MonthRange)):
   if MonthRange[i] == MonthNumber:
    ThreeMonthsAgo = MonthRange[i-2] #**************
print(ThreeMonthsAgo)

if ThreeMonthsAgo<MonthNumber:
if ThreeMonthsAgo >=10:
    stringthreemonthsagodate = "%s-%s-01"%(MonthlyReportDate.year, 
ThreeMonthsAgo)
else:
    stringthreemonthsagodate = "%s-0%s-01"%(MonthlyReportDate.year, 
ThreeMonthsAgo)

if ThreeMonthsAgo > MonthNumber:
if ThreeMonthsAgo >=10:
    stringthreemonthsagodate = "%s-%s-01"%(MonthlyReportDate.year - 1, 
ThreeMonthsAgo)
else:
    stringthreemonthsagodate = "%s-0%s-01"%(MonthlyReportDate.year - 1, 
ThreeMonthsAgo)

date_ranges = [(stringstartdate,
                stringenddate)]
data_ranges_for_three_months = [(stringthreemonthsagodate, stringenddate)]
```

It should run for the selected month but it runs only for the month of January.
I don't really get an error message but it is just not the right month.

---

It's been fixed. The solution is a bit embarrassing but i'll post it.All i had to do was whenever i change the month in macro, i need to save the .xlsm and then run it.

Comment: make sure that `March` is indeed on `Macro` sheet in cell `G10`. Or, try wrapping `sheet['G10'].value` in python `str`?

Comment: Are there any leading/trailing spaces in `G10`?

Comment: @BruceWayne what are those ? I'm sorry i'm new at this.

Comment: Meaning, make sure your cell is literally `March` or whatever month, and not say `    March`  or `March     ` (there are spaces either before or after "March" which can throw off the matching in Python).

Comment: This could be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Why are you trying to call a python script from VBA? Why not just do everything you need with VBA or Python?

Comment: @BruceWayne It's the way it was written. I am just taking over somebody.The person who wrote this code quit. I think it's because we use Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Run this code in the Excel spreadsheet:

```
Sub TestMe()
    MsgBox Worksheets("Macro").Range("G10")
End Sub
```

If you do not get "March", then you are most probably not referencing to `G10` but to something else.
Furthermore, you are openning the excel file through `Python` with enabled VBA. Are you sure, that whenever you open it, it does not reset back to `January`? This is called `Event()`.

Comment: I do get March when i run the code.What should i do now ?

Comment: @Satwant - save the excel file as `xlsx` and give it a try again. **Saving as `xlsx` would delete the code, thus make sure to make a copy!**

Comment: I did save it as xlsx but since it deleted the code the macro did not run. So i just changed the month to something other than January and ran the python script manually but it made no difference.

Comment: @Satwant - yes, the `xlsx` deletes the code in the worksheet. I though that you run the code from Python?

Comment: No i run it from VBA. My VBA calls the python script.

Answer (score 0):

It looks it's a caching / stale data issue.  If I am understanding you correctly, you run a VBA macro inside your workbook that calls a python script that then looks at a cell inside that same workbook?  Not an ideal structure!

When your python script calls the Excel sheet, here:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(pathOfMonthlyReportFile, keep_vba=True)
```

I think it's looking at the value of G10 when you last saved the file.  Perhaps the month was January on the last save?

I would either:

1. Restructure your python function so that it takes month and date arguments and pass those values when you call the function from VBA
2. Try having VBA save your sheet just before VBA calls the python script, thus preserving any changes made to the month and date dropdown.

Note that 1. is much more robust and professional than 2., but may be slightly more complicated to implement.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at my problem but the solution is a bit embarrassing but i'll post it.All i had to do was whenever i change the month in macro, i need to save the .xlsm and then run it. I know it's very stupid on my part.

Comment: Yes, my second suggestion!  You wouldn't have the save the sheet each time if you pass the python function the month and date as arguments instead.